# Does view property of view controller points to a window

Tags: ios, swift

From apple document:

> Each view controller manages a view hierarchy, the root view of which is stored in the view property of this class. The root view acts primarily as a container for the rest of the view hierarchy. The size and position of the root view is determined by the object that owns it, which is either a parent view controller or the app’s window. The view controller that is owned by the window is the app’s root view controller and its view is sized to fill the window.

And

[image]

As in the picture i understand that each view controller will have a window which is the root view. However, each app has only 1 window. In case of multiple view controllers in an app, I feel a little contradictory here . Where is my wrong understanding. Please help!
Thanks

Comment: you can add another window you want.

Comment: for better understating about view your can use , View hierarchy debugger ,

Comment: How can i open view debugger @Dhiru

Comment: see this , 

https://www.raywenderlich.com/98356/view-debugging-in-xcode-6

Comment: It still is not clear about my dout, please help explain more. Thanks

Comment: No, the `view` property of each view controller will **not** point to a window. Unless you create additional windows, your app will only have one window. The `rootViewController` property of the window defines the app’s root view controller. This view controller can be the parent of other view controllers and it will determine the size and position of their views.

Answer (score 1):

The diagram is not stating that every viewcontroller has its own window, it's merely stating that every viewcontroller has its own REFERENCE to the app's window. The root view controller's superview is the window of the app.